# AudioRecorder write same data to both chanel

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I have android TV + audio card with 2 microphones.
I'm trying to record in different files two stereo channels (one per file) using AudioRecorder.
But I'm getting the same data for both channels.
Original pcm data example(2 bytes per channel):

```
[79, -21, 79, -21, -1, -22, -1, -22, 58, -21, 58, -21, 13, -21, 13, -21, -114, -22, -114, -22, -27, -22, -27, -22,...
```

When I'm splitting it by channels, I'm getting two same arrays.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private Thread recordingThread = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;

int BufferElements2Rec;
int BytesPerElement = 2; // 2 bytes in 16bit format


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BufferElements2Rec = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
}

private void startRecording() {

    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,
            BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);

    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;
    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            writeAudioDataToFile();
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
}

private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    // Write the output audio in byte

    String firstFilePath = "/sdcard/origin.pcm";

    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(firstFilePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File rawLeftChannelDataFile = new File("/sdcard/first.pcm");
    File rawRightChannelDataFile = new File("/sdcard/second.pcm");

    FileOutputStream leftChannelFos = null;
    FileOutputStream rightChannelFos = null;
    try {
        leftChannelFos = new FileOutputStream(rawLeftChannelDataFile);
        rightChannelFos = new FileOutputStream(rawRightChannelDataFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedOutputStream leftChannelBos = new BufferedOutputStream(leftChannelFos);
    BufferedOutputStream rightChannelBos = new BufferedOutputStream(rightChannelFos);
    DataOutputStream leftChannelDos = new DataOutputStream(leftChannelBos);
    DataOutputStream rightChannelDos = new DataOutputStream(rightChannelBos);

    while (isRecording) {
        // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format

        //int readSize = recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
        byte[] bData = new byte[BufferElements2Rec];
        recorder.read(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
        try {
            // // writes the data to file from buffer
            // // stores the voice buffer
            byte[] leftChannelAudioData = new byte[bData.length / 2];
            byte[] rightChannelAudioData = new byte[bData.length / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < bData.length / 2; i += 2) {
                leftChannelAudioData[i] = bData[2 * i];
                leftChannelAudioData[i + 1] = bData[2 * i + 1];
                rightChannelAudioData[i] = bData[2 * i + 2];
                rightChannelAudioData[i + 1] = bData[2 * i + 3];
            }

            os.write(bData, 0, bData.length);
            leftChannelDos.write(leftChannelAudioData, 0, leftChannelAudioData.length);
            rightChannelDos.write(rightChannelAudioData, 0, leftChannelAudioData.length);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        os.close();
        leftChannelDos.close();
        rightChannelDos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Need AOSP base android.